# Can you spot the 3 Bugs in this JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, syntax, constructor

```
// This class takes a name string and greeting string in
// the constructor. Here are some examples of how this should work:
//
// g = new Greeter()
// g.greet() # => "Hello, Anonymous!"
//
// g = new Greeter("What's up", "Dog")
// g.greet() # => "What's up, Dog!"
//
// g = new Greeter("Hola")
// g.greet() # => "Hola, Anonymous!"
 
// Unfortunately, this code isn't quite working.
// Can you spot at least 2 bugs?
 
class Greeter {
  constructor(name, greeting) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = greeting;
  }
    
  greet() {
    const name = this.name;
    const greeting = this.greeting;
    
    if (!name) {
      name = "Anonymous";
    }
    if (greeting = undefined) {
      greeting = "Hello";
    }
    
    return "${greeting}, ${name}!";
  }
}
 
g = new Greeter("Hi")
g.greet()
```

Having trouble with my online assignment.
I'm not too familiar with using constructors for Classes so I cant find what's wrong with the syntax.

1. So far I've only identified using "const" as 1 bug, since that triggered the "Assignment to Constant Variable" error.

Comment: One hint: "[Difference Between =, ==, and === in JavaScript](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html)."

Comment: And... [template strings don't use quotes they use backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). `new Greeter('Hi')` - "Hi" (clearly a greeting) is being passed in as the first argument which should be the `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three bugs you have:

- Firstly, change `const` with `let`
- Secondly, use equal operator == not assign operator
- Thirdly use template string [``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) not `double quotes`

##### fixed:

```js
class Greeter {
    constructor(name, greeting) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    greet() {
    //1
    let name = this.name;
    let greeting = this.greeting;

    if (!name) {
        name = "Anonymous";
    }
    if (greeting == undefined) {
        //2
        greeting = "Hello";
    }

    return `${greeting}, ${name}!`; //3
    }
}

g = new Greeter("Hi");
g.greet(); //Hello, Hi!
```

Answer (score 1):

first mistake is line 9 instead of `const greeting = this.greeting` should be `let greeting = this.greeting`

second mistake is line 14 instead of `if (greeting = undefined)` should be `if (greeting == undefined)`

third mistake is line 18 instead of `return "${greeting}, ${name}!";` should be `return` ${greeting}, ${name}!`;